# Receiving "old" Intent data from Widget PendingIntent. How to clear out?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent, home-screen-widget

My `WidgetConfigActivity` creates an `onClickListener` `PendingIntent` to pass through `RemoteViews` to perform two tasks: (1) open `SliderActivity` and (2) pass the appropriate `appWidgetId`.

```
val views =RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget)
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(
    R.id.tv_widget_access_slider, 
    getSliderPendingIntent(this, appWidgetId)
)

fun getSliderPendingIntent(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): PendingIntent {
    val intent =Intent(context, SliderActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)  //tried this but didn't help
    Log.d("APP WIDGET PENDING INTENT", "$appWidgetId")
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
}
```

I need to get the `appWidgetId` in my `SliderActivity` so that the correct data can be displayed. So, I get the `intent` in `onCreate`.

```
val appWidgetId =intent.extras?.getInt("appWidgetId", 0) ?: 1
Log.d("APP WIDGET ID RECEIVED", "$appWidgetId")
intent.removeExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID)   //tried this but didn't help
```

It works except for one thing.  By logging, I've learned that the same `appWidgetId` is always received in `SliderActivity` `onCreate` even though unique `appWidgetIds` are added to the `PendingIntent`

***First widget added to home screen*** Pending intent id =**187**, Slider onCreate id =**187**

***Second widget added to home screen*** Pending intent id =**188**, Slider onCreate id =**187**

***Third widget added to home screen*** Pending intent id =**189**, Slider onCreate id =**187**

How can I get the correct `appWidgetId` to my widget `onClickListner` to my `SliderActivity`?

Comment: Add `FLAG_UPDATE` to  your `PendingIntent`. Also, do not use the same ID (`0` in  your code) for all `PendingIntent` objects -- use a distinct ID for each app widget.

Comment: @CommonsWare  `FLAG_UPDATE` does not seem to be an option??  Also, if I add a unique `RequestCode` in my `PendingIntent` do I also need to change the way I get the intent in `onCreate`?  Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare By simply adding my `appWidgetId` to the `requestCode` as you suggested fixed the issue.  Probably something I should have tried *facepalm*.  Thank you!  If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/PendingIntent?hl=en#flag_update_current).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each distinct app widget needs a distinct `PendingIntent`, where "distinct" is largely determined by the ID that you pass as the second parameter to the `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method. If you use the same ID for multiple app widgets, they all wind up using the same `PendingIntent`, despite code that otherwise looks like it is creating three `PendingIntent` objects.

If you need to change the contents of the `Intent` for a `PendingIntent`, use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as part of your flags in the `PendingIntent.getActivity()` call. Otherwise, an existing `PendingIntent` for that ID will be left alone.

IOW, think of `PendingIntent.getActivity()` as being a lazy-create mechanism — you need to take steps to force it to give you distinct objects and to update what is in them.